# Cloud service for storing app's resurces

Tags: android, storage, google-cloud-storage

Basically my question is really simple, but don't know how to search it.

My app will have:

1. a txt file with configuration details (most likely a json string in it)
2. 100 image files of max 1000x1000px in size

My app will parse the config file and read the images files path and download the images only when needed.

I simply need a storage service without database support.

Is there a free service that offer me this ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try the amazon AWS free usage tier and see if that would work for your purpose ? it provides the basic storage, and ability to run anything you need.
see them : http://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=AWS_Free_Tier_2013 
hope that helps.